# Bootstrap modal on Iphone - blank space

Tags: angularjs, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hi im using a bootstrap modal and when opened the modal on an iphone and tap to write, the phone keyboard shows up and i noticed that a blank space at the bottom is added, anyone experienced this issue before, just happens on ios safari.
[view issue here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P6iF.png)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue since iOS update last week.  Blank spaces in the code where my modals sit.  The ‘fix’ is to clear history and website data in settings, but that is not great for customer experience. Hope we can find a solution